# make a .saver file in xcode without using a screensaver type project

Tags: xcode, macos, screensaver

I am new to MacOS app development.

I want to make a custom screensaver for mac.

I found that we can make a custom screensaver file using xcode by starting a project of type ' **Screen Saver** '.

My doubt is, if I started a normal cocoa application and within that application, is it possible to create a screensaver file.

I saw an app like this called [iScreensaver](https://iscreensaver.com/)

can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you find an answer? I am trying to create a screen saver and I don't know if this is something the could be done programmatically or just using Adobe software.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a normal application, and a screen saver application, and then use a tool like File Merge to see how the projects from each template differ.

Then you could explore the project editor UI in Xcode to see if you could create a new target in a new project to match the screen saver target in the screen saver template.